# Async function returning before promise is resolved..JS, MondoDB, Twilio

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to get the list of lists from my db, format that list into a string containing 'name' in the list items and return the result. I thought I had the async and await set up properly, but the result is returned early as a promise before the promise is resolved. Any tips on getting an async function to not return until the promise is resolved?

```
exports.viewListsNamesSMS = async () => {

 let formatResult = (messages) => {
    let temp = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < messages.length; i ++)
        {
            temp.push(messages[i].name.toString());
        }
        return "Lists: \n" + temp.join('\n');
}



 let getListNames = async () => {
      let result = await db.List.find({}, (err, messages) => {
        if(err) return err;

        return formatResult(messages);
         });

         return result;
    }

let result = getListNames();

return result;

}
```

Comment: so, `db.List.find` returns a promise? doesn't look like it would, looks like a regular node callback style function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

db.List.find does not look like something that returns a Promise, so you'll need to Promisify it

```
exports.viewListsNamesSMS = () => {

    let formatResult = (messages) => {
        let temp = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < messages.length; i ++) {
            temp.push(messages[i].name.toString());
        }
        return "Lists: \n" + temp.join('\n');
    }

    let getListNames = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.List.find({}, (err, messages) => {
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(formatResult(messages));
                }
            });
    }
    return getListNames();
}
```

It may be useful to know that `async/await` doesn't just *wait for **any** asynchronous operation to complete* - it is syntactic sugar for Promises, so `await` will "wait" for a Promise to resolve

since the code you need is simple, with a single asynchronous operation thta doesn't itself return a Promise, there is no need to even use async/await at all - returning a Promise is all you need, as long as the code that calls this function is written to use Promises (or async await for that matter)

e.g.

```
viewListNamesSMS().then(results => process(results))
```

or

```
results = await viewListNamesSMS();
process(results)
```